# istio authorization policy and jwt check

Tags: istio

xx

Hello everyone,

I am playing with istio and security based on a JWT token.

I am able to deny access to services based on simple token elements (ie. when the field is of type key and simple value). I would like to know if we can create rules when the field value is an array. I am not able to figure out if it's possible after many tries.

For example, let's consider the JWT with the following data

```
{
  "sub": "user",
  "aud": "mgu",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "address",
    "email",
    "phone",
    "profile"
  ],
  "iss": "http://host.docker.internal:8001",
  "exp": 1670583577,
  "iat": 1670579977,
  "authorities": [
    "AUTH1",
    "AUTH2"
  ],
  "jti": "mgu-proxy"
}
```

I would like to allow access when one of the authorities is AUTH1.

I have tried with key of type

- key: request.auth.claims[authorities][*]
- key: request.auth.claims[authorities]

but none of them work.

Does someone know how to do it if it is possible?

Thanks for any help :)

PS: here is my AuthorizationPolicy.yaml file

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  action: ALLOW
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  rules:
  - when:
    - key: request.auth.audiences
      values: ["mgu"]
    - key: request.auth.claims[jti]
      values: ["mgu-proxy"]
```

and I have tried with (and many others...)

```
- key: request.auth.claims[authorities][*]
  values: ["AUTH1"]
```

and

```
- key: request.auth.claims[authorities]
  values: ["AUTH1"]
```